# How to repair the exception "non-null is null"?

Tags: kotlin

my app worked perfectly fine. Now I made the kotlin update and it throws me this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hdmc.smartristraveller, PID: 4788
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter location
    at com.hdmc.smartristraveller.fahrplanmap$onCreate$1.onSuccess(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.hdmc.smartristraveller.fahrplanmap$onCreate$1.onSuccess(fahrplanmap.kt:22)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:27)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I searched everywhere but I couldn't find the null parameter, does anyone know what could throw this exception?

Here my code for this class:

```
class fahrplanmap : AppCompatActivity() {
var webservices = webservices()
var StationID = IntArray(300)
var haltestellen_name : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
var haltestellen_lat: DoubleArray = DoubleArray(300)                        //all busstops
var haltestellen_lon: DoubleArray = DoubleArray(300)                        //all busstops
var StopDistances = DoubleArray(300)
var Haltestellen : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
var time = Handler()
var latitude = 0.0
var longitude = 0.0
companion object {
    private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
}

private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {                //wenn Bottom Navigationbar berührt wird
        R.id.navigation_Auskunft -> {
            //               message.setText(R.string.title_Auskunft)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_Abfahrtsmonitor -> {
            //               message.setText(R.string.title_Abfahrtsmonitor)
            val intent = Intent(this, Abfahrtsmonitor::class.java)        //Opens fahrplanmap Class
            startActivity(intent)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_Karte -> {
            //            message.setText(R.string.title_Karte)
            val intent = Intent(this, MapsAnzeigeActivity::class.java)  
            startActivity(intent)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_Meldungen -> {
           message.setText(R.string.title_meldungen)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_weiteres -> {
            message.setText(R.string.title_weiteres)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fahrplanmap)
    val navigation = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.navigation)       // findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.navigation)

    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    Haltestellen.clear()
    Recycleview2.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    Recycleview2.adapter = listadapter(haltestellen_name, this)
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), fahrplanmap.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        return
    }

    val locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as 
LocationManager

// Define a listener that responds to location updates

    val locationListener = object : LocationListener {

        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            println("GPS WOrks yeahhhh")
        }

        override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {
        }

        override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {
        }

        override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {
        }
    }

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0f,locationListener)
    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location ->
                if( location != null) {
                    latitude = location?.latitude
                    longitude = location?.longitude
                    println(latitude)
                    println(longitude)
                    println("gps?")

                    StopsFromWebservice().execute()
                }
            }
    println(fusedLocationClient.lastLocation)
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
}

fun FindClosestStops(){
    for (i in 0..haltestellen_lat.size-1){
        var x=0.0
        var y=0.0
        var distance = 0.0
        x= (haltestellen_lat[i]-latitude)*(haltestellen_lat[i]-latitude)
        y= (haltestellen_lon[i]-longitude)*(haltestellen_lon[i]-longitude)
        distance = sqrt(x+y)
        StopDistances[i]= distance

        Haltestellen.add(distance.toString())
    }
    SortDistance()
    time.post(UpdateView);
}

inner class StopsFromWebservice : AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {                      //Todo buslinien noch richtig stellen, von busroute zu lineid!!
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {
        webservices.get_Haltestellen()
        StationID = webservices.StationID
        haltestellen_name = webservices.Haltestellen
        haltestellen_lat = webservices.haltestellen_lat
        haltestellen_lon = webservices.haltestellen_lon     //todo schauen ob hintergrundprozess nötig
        FindClosestStops()

        return ""
    }

}
private val UpdateView = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        Recycleview2.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()                                                            //draws the route on maps
        time.postDelayed(this, 1000)

    }

}
fun deleteTimer(){
    time.removeCallbacks(UpdateView);
}
fun SortDistance(){
    var sorted = false
    var i = 0
    var k = 0
    while(k<haltestellen_name.size) {
        while (i < haltestellen_name.size - 1) {
            if (Haltestellen[i] > Haltestellen[i + 1]) {
                var dummy1 = Haltestellen[i]
                var dummy2 = haltestellen_name[i]

                Haltestellen[i] = Haltestellen[i + 1]
                haltestellen_name[i] = haltestellen_name[i + 1]

                Haltestellen[i + 1] = dummy1
                haltestellen_name[i + 1] = dummy2

            }
            i++
        }
        k++
        i=0
        println(k)
    }
    deleteTimer()
}
}
```

I am sorry for this unspecific question, what could trigger the null exception? It  doesnt even really start that I could search with the debugger. I tried deleting the gps handling code, but it didn't change anything

UPDATE:
I can start the app once on an emulator, the error appears from the second use onwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.addOnSuccessListener { location: Location ->`

By using `Location` and not `Location?` you're telling Kotlin that the listener only ever calls the callback with a non-null value. You're getting the error because this is not always true:

> If a location is not available, which should happen very rarely, null will be returned. The best accuracy available while respecting the location permissions will be returned.

Change the parameter type to be nullable and you will not get that error.

Its helpful to break down the generated function type:

- `fahrplanmap` - in `fahrplanmap`

  - `$onCreate` - function call in `onCreate`

    - `$1` - First anonymous class, implements `OnSuccessListener`

      - `.onSuccess` - `OnSuccessListener.onSuccess`